# Why read /dev/graphics/fb0 of screenshot is a battery icon?

Tags: android, linux, framebuffer

I use JNI  parse `/dev/graphics/fb0`, but the screenshot is a black-white battery icon. Why? It seems like fb0 don't any update for itself real-time

[image]